# Case Owner Update

Tags: case, case-object, owner

Kind of stuck, anyone have any input. When I create a new case for Internal Appeals and set the functional area to Benefits- Ops and status to Functional Area Review, the Case Owner is updated automatically. But when I have an already existing Case and update the functional area to Benefits-Ops and status to FAR, the case owner does NOT update and stays as my name. It should update automatically like it did when I created a new case.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the case object is configured. If it's a trigger, it might require an update in the code. If it's from Assignment Rules, checking the "Assign record using Assignment Rules" checkbox on the page should assign the owner correctly; if this option does not appear on the edit page, it can be added by a system administrator. If it's from a Flow update, it may require changing the value away from the criteria, saving, then switching the data back. In summary, there are a number of ways this could be assigned, so you'll need to check several different settings. You can also check the Debug Logs if you have sufficient access to determine how the owner is being changed.